# jupiter zerocode ParallelLoadExtension choose methods order

Tags: performance-testing, zerocode

Is it possible to use some kind of @Before annotation ?

I want to 'pre-load' datas (POST) before to launch my tests (GET).
But I only want parallel executions on the GET.
I was thinking to define a method with @LoadWith("preload_generation.properties") with :

```
number.of.threads=1
ramp.up.period.in.seconds=1
loop.count=1
```

Just to be sure that we execute it only once.
But it looks like I cannot choose the order of execution, and I need this POST method to be the first one executed.

I also tried to put a TestMappings with my 'loading method' at the top of the class.
But it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way that ZeroCode would be able to do this as it is specific to only re-leveraging tests already written in JUnit. My suggestion would be to follow a bit more traditional approach and use standard JUnit setup methods

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    // setup before the entire class
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    // setup before each individual test
}
```

rather than attempting to use a tool outside of its intended purposes.

As per your described scenario above that you want to ensure data is loaded before your tests are executed, especially in the case of being run under load by ZeroCode it is suggested that you determine how to create your data using the

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    // setup before the entire class
}
```

While this may take a bit more thought into how you create your data by creating it before all the tests it will ensure that your load test is excluding data setup time.